# Styling page-wide sections of an arbitrary page

Tags: 8, theming

Normally, the main content container is "centered" so that the page is, by default, not page wide. This works in 95% of the cases.

Except for when design calls for a page-wide section (i.e. centered content, but whose background spans the viewport width) on some arbitrary page. This requires hacks that look like the following, which I'd like to avoid.

```
// Introduces an uncalled for horizontal scroll bar
.page-wide {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50vw);
  width: 100vw;
}
```

On the other hand, another approach is to keep the main container always page-wide and have the content (types or individual pages), use layouts that do the centering. Works on anything that uses the Layout API but doesn't cover the cases that don't use the Layout API (e.g. system pages like the login screen, user screen).

What's the "canonical" way to do this in Drupal? How does one center content by default, but arbitrarily "break out" of this centering on certain pages without introducing odd hacks?

Comment: The canonical way to do this in Drupal would be "robust CSS". Not much Drupal involved.

Comment: The Drupal way to do this would be to create components via the Paragraphs module or similar. Then you can set width per each component. Some might be a constrained centered width and other components can be themed as full width. We do this all the time and it works great.

Comment: @DannyEnglander But this assumes that the page template main content is page-wide (and the paragraphs can center/uncenter within that wide area). How do you keep the other pages (e.g. system pages like user page, login, non-content pages) from being page-wide by default?

Comment: @Joseph I would create a new content type and call it something like "landing page" or "components" page. Then you can create a dedicated template for just that type. In D8, you can get fancy and use a block override method as as well. Or you could look at what I did here: https://www.dannyenglander.com/code/drupal-8-set-conditional-class/ which creates logic for switching.